# Redefine greek character outside of math mode

Tags: symbols, units

I am working with a publisher to write a book. The \mu command is used throughout the book. To prevent all uses from being italic, the publisher used \gdef to make all uses of \mu as \upmu.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{book}%

\usepackage{upgreek}%[euler]
\gdef\mu{\upmu}

\begin{document}%
$\mu$
$\upmu$
\end{document}
```

This technically works but returns an error that "\mu must be inside math mode" when it is used with \gdef. You can compile with and without the \gdef to see the difference in italics.

Any ideas how to clean this up to prevent the error?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Why `\gdef`? Why not just load the `amsmath` package (if you don't already do so) and run `\renewcommand{\mu}{\ensuremath{\upmu}}`? Please do give us your use case for using the upright lowercase-mu letter in text mode? Should you maybe be using `\textmu` instead of `\upmu`?

Comment: @Mico, the command is used in math mode throughout the book, and it is always used in a unit context. I believe the publisher is trying to match the format of the last edition of the book, where the `\upmu` symbol is what was used rather than the `\textmu` (very slight difference admittedly). The `\renewcommand` worked great.

Comment: By "unit context", you you mean something like 'micro-meter' and 'micro-second`? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico, yes exactly. The use of units (micro-meter, nano-second, etc.) in-text are generally denoted without italics. Throughout the book, the typesetters put `\mu` in math mode everywhere when it should have been intext, hence the redefinition. Frustrating, but `\renewcommand` seems to work fine. I admittedly don't fully understand why a global definition was desired here, but the renewed command isn't throwing any flags.

Answer (score 2):

(I came up with this answer after the OP provided some welcome additional information in the comments below the main posting.)

Please do yourself a huge favor and familiarize yourself with the [siunitx package](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) and its macros `\unit` -- to typeset scientific units -- and `\qty` -- to typeset  units together with their associated numerical quantities. Then, start writing things like

```
\unit{\micro\meter}, \unit{\nano\second}, \unit{\pico\farad}, \unit{\tera\joule}

\qty{15}{\mega\watt}, \qty{50}{\micro\meter}, \qty{33}{\kilo\gram}
```

Incidentally, `\unit` and `\qty` can be used in both text and math mode.

[image]

Observe "micro" characters, highlighted in yellow: they correspond to `\textmu`, *not* `\upmu`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{siunitx} % for \unit and \qty macros
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol} % optional (use "/" to denote fraction)

\begin{document}
\unit{\micro\meter}, \unit{\nano\second}, \unit{\pico\farad}, \unit{\tera\joule}

\qty{15}{\mega\watt}, \qty{50}{\micro\meter}, \qty{33}{\kilo\gram}

\unit{\meter\per\second}, \unit{\meter\per\second\squared}, \unit{\kilo\gram\metre\per\square\second}
\end{document}
```